# New package -> missing $ inserted

Tags: math-mode, errors

I don't know how to explain my problem.

I have this code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{envmath}

\newcommand\irrev{\(\rightarrow \ \)}
\begin{document}

            \irrev

\end{document}
```

(a test code) which works but when I add the package envmath I have the following error :

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
            $
l.8 \irrev
```

What's wrong ? Is the package ? How can I use it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation of the package makes clear, it provides non standard definitions of `\(` and related commands.

You can use `$`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{envmath}

\newcommand\irrev{$\rightarrow \ $}
\begin{document}

            \irrev

\end{document}
```

Or not use the package, depending on requirements.

Comment: Ok, so there are packages which redefine \(.  Have I right understand ? (Sorry, i'm not fluent in english, I may have some misunderstandings)

Comment: @Ccile yes I had never used envmath so to answer your question I  looked at its documentation (`texdoc envmath`)  and it states in the very first section on page 1 that it redefines `\(` and you have to use `$` or `\begin{math}` to start math mode.

Comment: (I looked at  mathenv instead of envmath documentation....)

Do you think it could be a good practice to always use \\begin{math} (or displaymath) to avoid this kinf of problem ?

Comment: @Ccile there are very few packages that would redefine a standard latex command in such an incompatible way. I do not know what that package does or why you need it, but it's not really a general problem but just a problem with this package, not a bug, but rather a well documented and intentional incompatibility.